# How to use Profiler samples to profile Start method?

Tags: unity, c#, profiling, profiler

When I use `Profiler.BeginSample("Update Example")` and `Profiler.EndSample()` in `Update()`, I can see "Update Example" in `Update.ScriptRunBehaviorUpdate` in the profiler window.

But when I use `Profiler..."Start Example"...` in `Start()`, I cannot see or find any mention in the profiler. Is there any way to track code in `Start()`?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    BoxParameter bParameter;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Start Example");
        bParameter = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<ZombieInventory>().box;
        Debug.Log(bParameter.width);
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Profiler.BeginSample("Update Example");
        bParameter = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<ZombieInventory>().box;
        Debug.Log(bParameter.width);
        Profiler.EndSample();
    }
```